# Why does Chrome use a lower order font for a UTF-8 glyph character when an earlier font already has that character?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, utf-8, fonts

I'm using Bootstrap 4. Chrome displays the UPWARDS BLACK ARROW (⬆) as

[image]

[Bootstrap lists the default fonts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/#native-font-stack) as

```
$font-family-sans-serif:
  // Safari for OS X and iOS (San Francisco)
  -apple-system,
  // Chrome < 56 for OS X (San Francisco)
  BlinkMacSystemFont,
  // Windows
  "Segoe UI",
  // Android
  "Roboto",
  // Basic web fallback
  "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif,
  // Emoji fonts
  "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol" !default;
```

"Segoe UI" (and "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif) displays UPWARDS BLACK ARROW (⬆) as

[image]

It is "Segoe UI Emoji" which is displaying a blue boxed arrow. Why does Chrome use that font even though it is second from last in the `font-family` list and other fonts already render it?

```css
.bs-font {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji";
}
.sui-font {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Emoji";
}
```

```html
<span class="bs-font">⬆</span><br/>
<span class="sui-font">⬆</span>
```